# Open RDP in 99% of full screen

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a laptop that I connect to diff. kind of monitors.

Normally my RDP opens in full screen.

But I would like it to only open in 99%, so that it's not the RDP thats in focus but still my laptop.

I know I can open in any resolution I put into RDP file.

But I cant figure out how to fit RDP to 99%, so that it will fit all kind of monior sixzes I use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go the trouble setting it to 99%. Instead, just make it 100% but windowed, and enable smart sizing.

With the connection active, click on the icon in the top left to open the menu, and select the option Smart Sizing (you can also put this in an .RDP) file to have it enabled by default.

Once set, if you now resize the window, it will always keep this resolution in the window, but scale the image up/down to fit the size of the window.

[image]

Here is what it looks like after smart sizing is enabled, and I then make the window really tiny:
[image]

Comment: Ok thanks.. will look at it. But if I move from a 27" monitor to 49" then I still will have to do a manual rezising or? Actually I would like my RDP window to fill out my monitor, but still have access to my laptop desktop. F. ex. I have a program on my laptop that I activate with a short key command. If rdp window is full size, my short key cant activate the program. If RDP is just 99% I can activate program with shortkey. Therefore I always use 100% and then I manually adjust RDP picture to fit the screen about 99%.

Comment: With auto scale on, it will always use the same internal resolution on the remote side, but the window is scaled. So if its perfectly visible on the 27" everything will look zoomed in on the 49". If its perfectly visible on the 49" then on the 27" it will look zoomed out. You can find a middle ground resolution or see which of the two works best for what you want. Alternatively, just create 2 RDP files, one for the 27" monitor and one for the 49" monitor.